# Handlers don't end after calling removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)

Tags: java, android, handler

I have two handlers. Handler in a handler. Both of them are in a for-loop.

The overview is something like this,

```
for{
    handler.postDelayed(runnableA{
        for{
            handler2.postDelayed(runnableB{
                function();
            }, 3000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

I wanted to end handlers' work at any time when the user clicks `back button`. So, I created two Runnable Classes so that I can use something like `runnableA.removellbacksAndMessages(null)`.

```
Handler messageHandler;
Handler countDownHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Start Play in 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    countDownHandler = new Handler();

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
        final int idx = i;
        Runnable countRunnable = new CountRunnable(idx, countDownView);
        countDownHandler.postDelayed(countRunnable, 1000 * (7 - i));
    }
}
```

And this is Runnable Classes.

```
public class CountRunnable implements Runnable {
    int idx;
    TextView countDownView;

    public CountRunnable(int idx, TextView countDownView) {
        this.idx = idx;
        this.countDownView = countDownView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int messageSize = messageItems.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < messageSize; j++) {
            final int jdx = j;
            messageHandler = new Handler();
            Runnable messageRunnable = new MessageRunnable(jdx);
            messageHandler.postDelayed(messageRunnable, 3000 * jdx);
        }
    }
}

class MessageRunnable implements Runnable {
    int jdx;

    public MessageRunnable(int jdx) {
        this.jdx = jdx;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        addMessageView(messageItems.get(jdx));
    }
}
```

This is `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All Work Ended.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    scrollFlag = true;

    try {
        messageHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "messageHandler never used");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        countDownHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
public void addMessageView(String message){
    try{
        mTextView.setText(message);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Abnormal End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But, I keep getting errors because the activity already ended but the handlers can't find the activity. So, `Abnormal End` Toast message shows as many as the size of inner for loop.

I can ignore this if I don't use the Toast message, but I am afraid of Memory leak or Bad formed Program or something like that.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You have one variable `messageHandler` and replace it `7 * messageSize[i]` times. Your app only remembers the last `messageHandler` stored. You only need to create the handler once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are creating `n` numbers of `CountRunnable`s and `m` number `MessageRunnables`. Despite creating more than one numbers of handlers you are removing callbacks only for the latest-created `Hanlder`.

Here's what you should do:

Keep a reference of all the `Handler`s and `Runnables` and call `messageHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` and `countDownHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` on all of them.